# how to send image (bitmap) to server in android with multipart-form data json

Tags: android

I have code to upload image to server and it works ,

```
HttpEntity resEntity;

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(Constants.url_create_product);
                MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                File file= new File(path);
                FileBody bin = new FileBody(file);

                reqEntity.addPart("phone", new StringBody(mPhoneNumber));
                reqEntity.addPart("prod_title", new StringBody(namapro));
                reqEntity.addPart("prod_price", new StringBody(hargapro));
                reqEntity.addPart("prod_desc", new StringBody(despro));
                reqEntity.addPart("prod_order", new StringBody(orderpro));
                reqEntity.addPart("prod_image", bin);

                post.setEntity(reqEntity);
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
                resEntity = response.getEntity();
                String response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
                Gson gson = new Gson(); 
                gson.toJson(response_str);
                 if (resEntity != null) {
                     Log.i("RESPONSE",response_str);
                     runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                            public void run() {
                                 try {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Upload Complete. Check the server uploads directory.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                               }
                        });
                 }
```

But i have menu image editor . that editor is crop image and thats code return bitmap value like this

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

                if (extras != null) {               
                    photo = extras.getParcelable("data");

                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                }

                File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());            

                if (f.exists()) f.delete();

                break;
```

I wanna ask , how solution to send image to server with parameter bitmap. As you know my code to send image now use parameter path (string).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Then send this encodedImage as a `String` and in your server you will need to decode it in order to get the image itself.

Comment: sorry , iam newbie , so how server to decode it in order to get the image itself??

Comment: depends on what language you're using on your server. PHP has built in method for this. Just google the language on server + decode image string.

Comment: @carnal, i am getting image url is http://........exam1.jpg and i converted to bitmap but not for this photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);

Comment: That is base64 not multipart!

Answer (score 5):

*use three library
1.httpclient-4.3.6
2.httpcore-4.3.3
3.httpmime-4.3.6

```
            byte[] data = null;
            try {    
                String url = "http://andapp.freetings.in/testbyme.php?";
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url); 
                MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

                if(imageBitmap!=null){
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    imageBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                    data = bos.toByteArray();
                    entity.addPart("uplod_img", new ByteArrayBody(data,"image/jpeg", "test2.jpg"));
                }
                // entity.addPart("category", new StringBody(categoryname,"text/plain",Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                entity.addPart("category", new StringBody(catid,"text/plain",Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                entity.addPart("your_contact_no", new  StringBody(phone,"text/plain",Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                entity.addPart("your_emailid", new StringBody(email,"text/plain",Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                entity.addPart("your_name", new StringBody(name,"text/plain",Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

                httppost.setEntity(entity);
                HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(httppost);          
                HttpEntity resEntity = resp.getEntity();
                String string=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
                //  Log.e("sdjkfkhk", string);
                return resEntity;
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Unable to find ByteArrayBody

Comment: u have need add  three jar file those are httpclient-4.1.jar, httpcore-4.1.jar and httpmime-4.1.jar  in libs folder