# Uri to Bitmap Issue

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-volley, multipartform-data, androidhttpclient

I am getting profile image as a Uri from Google signin and now want to send that image on another server.

So following is the Class i am using for the same.

**MultipartUtility.java**

```
public class MultipartUtility {
    private final String boundary;
    private static final String LINE_FEED = "\r\n";
    private HttpURLConnection httpConn;
    private String charset;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private PrintWriter writer;

    /**
     * This constructor initializes a new HTTP POST request with content type
     * is set to multipart/form-data
     *
     * @param requestURL
     * @param charset
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public MultipartUtility(String requestURL, String charset)
            throws IOException {
        this.charset = charset;

        // creates a unique boundary based on time stamp
        boundary = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";
        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true);    // indicates POST method
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset),
                true);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a form field to the request
     *
     * @param name  field name
     * @param value field value
     */
    public void addFormField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"")
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(
                LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a upload file section to the request
     *
     * @param fieldName  name attribute in <input type="file" name="..." />
     * @param uploadFile a File to be uploaded
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void addFilePart(String fieldName, File uploadFile)
            throws IOException {
        String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(
                "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + fieldName
                        + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(
                "Content-Type: "
                        + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName))
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        inputStream.close();
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a header field to the request.
     *
     * @param name  - name of the header field
     * @param value - value of the header field
     */
    public void addHeaderField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append(name + ": " + value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Completes the request and receives response from the server.
     *
     * @return a list of Strings as response in case the server returned
     * status OK, otherwise an exception is thrown.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public List<String> finish() throws IOException {
        List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();
        writer.append(LINE_FEED).flush();
        writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.close();

        // checks server's status code first
        int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpConn.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.add(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            httpConn.disconnect();
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status);
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

**Callback:**

```
MultipartUtility multipart = new MultipartUtility(url, "UTF-8");
            multipart.addFormField("token", token);
            multipart.addFormField("user_id", userid);
            multipart.addFormField("email", email);
            multipart.addFormField("name", name);
            multipart.addFilePart("image", folder);
```

> Following is the error i am getting: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   https:/lh5.googleusercontent.com/-IsN40fH-ld4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AAomvV1zuROxSSb-oMcEht44cCMEXmZQiw/s96-c/photo.jpg:
>   open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

**Image File i am sending to server : https:/lh5.googleusercontent.com/-IsN40fH-ld4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AAomvV1zuROxSSb-oMcEht44cCMEXmZQiw/s96-c/photo.jpg**

Please help me with this.

Comment: u can store your image in form of 64 bit string as well.!

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi i want to send in form of jpg/png.

Comment: first you need to download this image After that  can send this image to another server.

Comment: You are trying to create a new FileInputStream on an url. That will not work of course. You should stsrt relizing this.

Comment: `profile image as a Uri from Google signin`. No not an uri but a url string starting with https.

Comment: @greenapps   i realized it.  Thats why asking for help,an advice or other way around. How to handle....

Comment: @greenapps : Below method og Google for getting an profile image. Its returning Uri. 
    public Uri getPhotoUrl() {
        return this.dD;
    }

Comment: Then show how you use that uri calling addFilePart().

Comment: @greenapps         File folder = new File(uri.getPath);

Comment: Well you cannot use the File class on an url string starting with https://. And what you have to do instead has long been said by Rajkumar Kumawat.

Comment: @greenapps okay i will try that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you processing your File folder like below -

```
File folder =null;
folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+"name.png");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(folder);
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,90,fos);
```

try to add these lines.

Comment: i am getting image from server.

Comment: Then try to save the image first and get the image ,convert it to file format and then send it to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try To Read this Tutorial.! [Image Uri To Bitmap](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/25/converting-image-url-to-bitmap/)

Comment: i dont want to set into imageview. I want to send to server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796579/how-to-send-image-bitmap-to-server-in-android-with-multipart-form-data-json try thi slink

Comment: this one will solve your problem hope so.!

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/

Comment: Another link http://www.codepool.biz/take-a-photo-from-android-camera-and-upload-it-to-a-remote-php-server.html