# how to send image from recyclerview imageview to other activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerview with card view. each card contains imageview with one image which is retrieved from firebase database using Picasso.now what I want to do is whenever I clicked on the imageview it will open that image in a new activity.i'm able to open new activity by clicking on imageview.but it not showing the image.

for this I used below code in my adapter class :

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
private List<RecyclerClass>listdata ;

public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<StreetClass> list) {

    this.listdata = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.show_items, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

   public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

      RecyclerClass Details = listdata.get(position);
      Picasso.with(context).load(Details.getImgurl()).resize(120, 60).into(holder.ImageTextView);
      holder.ImageTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            //add data to your bundle
            bundle.putInt("id", position);
            //create intent
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, ShowImage.class);
            //add bundle to intent
            mainIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            //start activity
            context.startActivity(mainIntent);

        }
    });
```

in other class, i used this code but i don't know is it right or wrong

```
public class ShowImage extends AppCompatActivity {

Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_image);

    ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.shwimg);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    int position = i.getIntExtra("id", 0);
    img.setImageResource(ArrayList.get(position));

}
}
```

please, help me

Comment: ArrayList.get(position -->what it returns

Comment: Try,  `Picasso.with(context).load(ArrayList.get(position).getImgurl()).into(img);`

Comment: here, ArrayList is your list which you have used in adapter. Make it as static and also public

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get recyclerview image data in mainactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45117718/how-to-get-recyclerview-image-data-in-mainactivity)

Comment: if your List is static try to get url from it and Load with Picasso , Developer sad that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to send the image url instead of position. Change the contents of `onclick` method in adapter like this

```
 Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, ShowImage.class);
 mainIntent.putExtra("img_url", Details.getImgurl());
 context.startActivity(mainIntent);
```

And in ShowImage activity save it like this

```
 Intent i = getIntent();
 String image = i.getStringExtra("img_url");
 Picasso.with(ShowImage.this).load(image).resize(120, 60).into(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be just sending imageUrl from your adapter to the activity as a string extra. Then using that with picasso to load the image, exactly like you did in your adapter

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside the click listener

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putExtra("img_url", Details.get(position).getImgurl());
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, ShowImage.class);
mainIntent.putExtras(bundle);
((Activity)context).startActivity(mainIntent);
```

In the activity class add the following for getting the image url

```
String url = getIntent.getStringExtra("img_url);
```

And set it to the corresponding image view as you have done in the adapter class

Answer (score 0):

Here, you only pass the position of RecyclerView's item instead of passing the image.So, you need to pass the image by using intent like this:

```
            //create intent
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, ShowImage.class);
            //add bundle to intent
           intent.putExtra("img", Details.getImgurl());
            //start activity
            context.startActivity(mainIntent);
```

Get Intent in Another Activity like this:

```
  String imgurl= getIntent().getStringExtra("img");
Picasso.with(this).load(imgurl).resize(120, 60).into(img);
```